# the tables are bank_sb_account ,bank_transaction

Tags: oracle

Show transaction details – SB a/c no., transaction type, date, description and amount, for transaction amounts > 1000. Sort the output based on a/c no, transaction type and date.

Comment: So that's it?  You just throw out a homework question and expect someone to know and understand the tables involved and write a solution for you?  1) this is not a code-writing service, 2) no one can write queries without knowledge of the details of the tables involved; just the names of the tables is meaningless 3) most people are not inclined to help with homework without seeing some evidence of effort on your part.

Comment: Please read 'How to Create a minimal reproducible example.  Here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

The way you described it, that would be something like this:

```
select sb a/c no., transaction type, description, amount
from some table
where amount > 1000
order by a/c no, transaction type, date
```

Of course, it won't work, column names can't have those names (at least, some of them), but - you didn't put much effort in question, so don't expect *miracle* on my side.

Also, what does "solution is not getting accepted" mean?

Comment: the account_no is of another table bank_sb_account and the transaction related rest things of another table bank_transaction and btw it was my first question so i made the mistake in giving less info and what you wrote is not accepted as the output and i thought of same solution

Comment: btw for any kind of joins there should be a column same in both tables  right???